# React js формирование JSX на основе строки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день. Использую React JS. Render компонента. У меня есть динамическая строка:

```
var string = "#k - #score - #date":
```

Мы точный порядок не знаем. И предположим что таких "меток" в строке очень большое количество.

У нас есть объект с ключами этих меток и jsx шаблоном соответствующий метке

```
var template = {
   "#k" : <div>Комадна</div>,
   "#score" : <span>Результат</span>
};
```

Размер этого объекта всегда равен количеству меток в строке выше.

так вот. Рендер должен возвратить на основе этой строки jsx шаблон . Как это реализовать?

Спасибо

Comment: А вы посмотрите, во что преобразуется JSX, возможно, вам проще формировать сразу результат, чем идти таким окольным путём.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пример работы:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    templates = {
        "#k" : <span>Комадна</span>,
        "#score" : <span>Результат</span>
    };

    renderText = (text, regExp, fn) => {
        const parts = text.split(regExp);

        for (let index = 1; index < parts.length; index += 2) {
            parts[index] = fn(parts[index], index);
        }

        return parts;
    };

    matchValue (match) {
        if (match === '') {
            return match;
        }

        if (this.templates.hasOwnProperty(match)) {
            return this.templates[match];
        }

        return match;
    }

    renderNextLine (text) {
        if (!text) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.renderText(text, /(#[a-zA-Z]+)/g, this.matchValue.bind(this))
    }

    render () {
        const string = "#k - #score - #date";

        return <div>
            {this.renderNextLine(string)}
        </div>
    }
}
```

**Расшифровка:**
Нам нужно разобрать полученную строку регуляркой так, чтобы получить структурированный массив, где определенные элементы этого массива, будут являться ключем к нашему "шаблону".

Разбираем код по регулярке `(#[a-zA-Z]+)`, и получаем такой набор. Далее применяем к каждому нечетному элементу наш рендер-шаблон, в котором ищем совпадение с набором `templates`. И наконец подменяем.

Я такой подход использовал для `draft-js`, когда делал кастомный рендер определенных вещей.

Comment: В данном примере на выходе мы утеряем все пробелы и другие символы без # .

Comment: К примеру. Строка

"#k - #score - #date"

Вернет <div>Комадна</div><span>Результат</span> , а остальные символы будут утеряны

Comment: Хм, ну да, я не понял с начала что вы хотите сделать обычную замену на некоторых "шаблоно-именах". Я делал похожее, если сделаю пример, скину

Comment: @devn проверяйте, должно удовлетворять вашим требованиям)

Comment: Супер спасибо))